# Error sorting dataframe column by decreasing

Tags: r, sorting

I've this dataframe of two columns being the first one words(Word)and the second one their frequency (Freq) . I'm using the sort() function but apparently I keep falling into the same trap. My code, followed by the error, is:

```
  sorted <- sort(df, order(df$Freq, decreasing= TRUE))


  Error in sort(freqmat, order(freqmat$Freq, decreasing = TRUE)) : 
 'decreasing' must be a length-1 logical vector.
  Did you intend to set 'partial'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It don't think you mean to sort again after ordering by frequency. If you want to rearrange the rows by frequency:

```
sorted <- df[order(df$Freq, decreasing= TRUE),]
```